# QGIS 2.14.1 Processing Plug-In does not work anymore (Python error)

Tags: qgis, python, error

I did not change anything and started QGIS 2.14.1 today and was greeted with the following error message. So the Processing tab is missing and I cannot activate it.

The error:

```
2016-04-26T17:58:43 1   Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 315, in startPlugin plugins[packageName].initGui()
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\ProcessingPlugin.py", line 57, in initGui
                Processing.initialize()
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 148, in initialize
                Processing.loadFromProviders()
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 165, in loadFromProviders
                Processing.loadAlgorithms()
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 200, in loadAlgorithms
                Processing.updateProviders()
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 173, in updateProviders
                provider.loadAlgorithms()
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\AlgorithmProvider.py", line 54, in loadAlgorithms
                self._loadAlgorithms()
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\otb\OTBAlgorithmProvider.py", line 61, in _loadAlgorithms
                version = OTBUtils.getInstalledVersion(True)
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\otb\OTBUtils.py", line 143, in getInstalledVersion
                out = executeOtb(commands, progress, False)
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISES~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\otb\OTBUtils.py", line 169, in executeOtb
                os.putenv('ITK_AUTOLOAD_PATH', otbLibPath())
TypeError: must be string, not None
```

What is wrong suddenly?

Comment: This issue is less of a GIS question and more of a software issue. I suggest removing qgis completely (uninstall) and then reinstall qgis and the plug in. After this try to install the plug in again. Could also be the plug in is not compatible withe 2.14.1 Unless it is native.

Comment: Updating to 2.14.2 solved the issue.